# Area Chart Graph in android

Tags: android

I want to implement an Area Chart Graph in android.I prefer Area chart graph because i want to color the area of my graph.The Graph is draw using some calcutions.AnyOne have an idea reagrding how to implement the area chart graph??

Comment: A good starting point would probably be to have a around at what Android charting libraries support drawing area charts. From personal experience I can tell that `achartengine` supports this type of chart, so you might want to check that out. The demos include an [area chart sample](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/SalesComparisonChart.java) (screenshots [here](http://www.achartengine.org/content/demo.html)).

Comment: thanks MH...but does we can any code that is easy to understand other than these available on area chart sample

Comment: Well, I suppose you don't want to go and reinvent the wheel again, so I suggest you have a look at what's 'out there' first. Also, "easy to understand" doesn't really mean anything without providing a context. Drawing a chart from scratch will surely involve quite some code, so I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for here?

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer you are looking for: [Click Here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-drawing-area-chart-using-achartengine/)